# Evaluator.PartialEval reduce provided expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression-trees

In one of my projects I have an ExpressionVisitor to translate provided expression into some query string. But before translating it I need to evaluate all refferences in the expression to real values. To do that I use [Evaluator.PartialEval](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Caching/Query/Evaluator.cs) method from EntityFramework Project.

Assuming I have this query:

```
 var page = 100;
 var query = myService.AsQueryable<Product>()
              //.Where(x=>x.ProductId.StartsWith(p.ProductId))
                .Skip(page)
                .Take(page);

var evaluatedQueryExpr = Evaluator.PartialEval(query.Expression);
```

As you can see I have commented Where method. In this case evaluatedQueryExpr will not contain the methods Take and Skip.

However, if I use any other method with Expression before Take or Skip everything works, Evaluator evaluates an expression correctly and return it fully.

I found out that the problem occurs in the line 80 of the Evaluator class:

```
return Expression.Constant(fn.DynamicInvoke(null), e.Type);
```

Could you explain why this happens and suggest a workaround?

**Update**
here is [a project on github](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr)

[LinqToSolrQueriable inherited from IOrderedQueryable](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr/blob/master/LinqToSolr/Query/LinqToSolrQueriable.cs)
[LinqToSolrProvider inherited from IQueryProvider](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr/blob/master/LinqToSolr/Query/LinqToSolrProvider.cs#L59-L65) including line range causing the issue

Comment: I don't see this... `var evaluatedQueryExpr = Evaluator.PartialEval(new[] { new Product { }, new Product { } }.AsQueryable<Product>().Skip(page).Take(page).Expression)` on other `IQueryable<>`... It could be a "special effect" of EF `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: But note that for the `Skip(page)` you won't "enter" line 80: the `Skip(page)` is already a `Skip(100)` in `query`. The variable `page` is "read" when the variable `query` is initialized. So the lines 74-76 are executed: `if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant) { return e;` (*100* is a constant).

Comment: this is what I cannot understand. I debug the Evaluate method. I see that I pass an expression to this method `{value(Linq.SolrQueryable'1[Product]).Skip(100).Take(100)}`. 

But inside it in line 80 `Expression.Constant(fn.DynamicInvoke(null), e.Type))`it is already converted to `{value(SolrQueryable'1[Product])}`. However your pure example works correctly :( so for some reason `fn.DynamicInvoke` loose take and skip when no 'where' provided before.

Comment: I don't see an issue when I replace `myService` with an array of anonymous objects. I think we may need to know more about your source?

Comment: @NetMage well, this is [a project on github](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr/tree/master/LinqToSolr). This is [a LinqToSolrQueriable](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr/blob/master/LinqToSolr/Query/LinqToSolrQueriable.cs) and this is [a LinqToSolrProvider](https://github.com/DanielLavrushin/LinqToSolr/blob/master/LinqToSolr/Query/LinqToSolrProvider.cs#L57-L62)  (see line  50 and 62). Maybe you may have a look? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news are that the expression is not really reduced (`Skip` and `Take` are still there :), but is simply converted from `MethodCallExpression` to `ConstantExpression` *containing* the original expression:

*query.Expression*:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Take(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Skip(
        .Constant<LinqToSolr.Query.LinqToSolrQueriable`1[LinqToSolrTest.Product]>(LinqToSolr.Query.LinqToSolrQueriable`1[LinqToSolrTest.Product]),
        100),
    100)
```

*evaluatedQueryExpr:*

```
.Constant<System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LinqToSolrTest.Product]>(LinqToSolr.Query.LinqToSolrQueriable`1[LinqToSolrTest.Product])
```

Here the debug display is giving you a wrong impression. If you take the `ConstaintExpression.Value`, you'll see that it's a `IQueryable<Product>` with `Expression` property being exactly the same as the original `query.Expression`.

The bad news are that this is not what you expect from `PartialEval` - in fact it doesn't do anything useful in this case (except potentially breaking your query translation logic).

*So why is this happening?*

The method you are using from [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) library is in turn taken (as indicated in the comments) from MSDN Sample [Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx). It can be noticed that the `PartialEval` method has two overloads - one with `Func<Expression, bool> fnCanBeEvaluated` parameter used to identify *whether a given expression node can be part of the local function* (in other words, to be partially evaluated or not), and one without such parameter (used by you) which simply calls the first passing the following predicate:

```
private static bool CanBeEvaluatedLocally(Expression expression)
{
    return expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Parameter;
}
```

The effect is that it stops evaluation of `ParameterExpression` type expressions *and any expressions containing* directly or indirectly `ParameterExpression`. The last should explain the behavior you are observing. When the query contains `Where` (and basically any LINQ operator) *with parametrized lambda expression* (hence *parameter*) before the `Skip` / `Take` calls, it would stop evaluation of the containing methods (which you can see from the above `query.Expression` debug view - the `Where` call will be inside the `Skip`).

Now, this overload is used by the MSDN example to evaluate a *concrete nested* `Where` method lambda expression and is not generally applicable for any type of expression like `IQueryable.Expression`. In fact the linked project is using the `PartialEval` method in a single place inside [QueryCache](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Caching/Query/QueryCache.cs#L28) class, and also calling the other overload passing a [different predicate](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Caching/Query/QueryCache.cs#L43) which in addition to `ParameterExpressions` stops the evaluation of any expression with result type of `IQueryable`.

Which I think is the solution of your problem as well:

```
var evaluatedQueryExpr = Evaluator.PartialEval(query.Expression,
    // can't evaluate parameters or queries
    e => e.NodeType != ExpressionType.Parameter &&
        !typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(e.Type)
);
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you so much for spending time and finding this! I appreciate for your detailed answer and  explanation. Now it works as expected!

Comment: You are welcome mate, glad it helped :) Happy coding!